# jquery array image fade background

Tags: jquery, arrays, image, background, fadein

i need to create an image transition / fader in jquery which simultaneously changes the background colour of the parent container...

I need to be able to pass on a 2-dim array containing setd of the images and the matching background colour.

```
<div id="parent">

    <div id="some_div">with some information (should not be changed)</div>
    <div id="image_holder">this image has to be replaced</div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe I don't understand your question.  This is pretty trivial to do:

```
var imgs = [{url:'foo.jpg', bg:'#f00'}, {url:'bar.jpg', bg:'#00f'}];

function changeImage(idx)
{
    $('#image_holder').attr('href', imgs[idx].url);
    $('#parent').css({backgroundColor:imgs[idx].bg});
}
changeImage(1);
```

This doesn't do transitions, but that depends on what kind of transition you want to do (crossfade/etc).